# How do you do the rest of this op-amp question?

Tags: overleaf, opamp

This is what I have done in LaTeX so far but I am struggling with the labling and overlap of lines and the RHS of the picture

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
      (opamp.-) to[short,-*] ++(-1, 0) coordinate(A)
      (opamp.+) to[R,l_=$2k\Omega$,-o] ++(-2, 0)-| ++(-0.25,-1) node[ground](B){}
      (opamp.out) to[short,*-o] ++(1, 0) coordinate(C)
      (A) to[R,l_=$12k\Omega$,-o] ++(-2, 0) -- ++(-1, 0) coordinate(D) to [V<=$12V$] (D |- B) node[ground]{}
      (A) |- ++(1,1) coordinate[yshift=1ex] (L1) to[R=$5k\Omega$] ++(2,0) -| (opamp.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my answer on your previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640500/how-do-you-replicate-this-op-amp-question):

```
\documentclass[border=3.131592]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw   (0,0)   to[R,l=\qty{12}{\kilo\ohm}] ++(2,0) coordinate[label=below:$V_1$] (in-)
                to[short,i=$i_1$, *-]       ++(1,0)
                node[op amp,
                     anchor=-]  (oa) {}
(in- |- oa.+)   coordinate[label=$V_2$] (in+)
                to[short,i=$i_2$, *-]   (oa.+)
    (oa.out)    to[short,*-o]               ++(1, 0) coordinate (out+)
        (in-)   to[short]                   ++(0,2)  coordinate (aux1)
                to[R,l=\qty{5}{\kilo\ohm}]    (aux1 -| oa.out)
                to[short]               (oa.out)
        (in+)   to[R,l=\qty{2}{\kilo\ohm}]  ++(0,-3) coordinate (aux2)
                to[short,*-o]           (aux2 -| out+)    coordinate (out-)
                to[open, v=$V_o$, o-o]  (out+)
        (0,0)   to[V,a=\qty{12}{\volt}] (0,0 |- out-)
                to[short]               (aux2);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]